# What is best way to convert List into comma separated String to pass in SQL while querying database?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, java-8

I have a list of ids

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

I want to write a delete query

```
public void deleteComputersUsingNative(List<Integer> id) {
    String commaSeperated = ?//Convert ID to  comma seperated string in to put in where clause
    em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM PD_OWNER.CIM_SNOW_COMP_OPTDRIV_TAB WHERE ID IN (" +commaSeperated +")").executeUpdate();
}
```

To do `toString()` and remove the brackets in one solution.

Is there a better way to handle this in plain java or maybe in jpa/hibernate?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.join`:

```
String.join(',', id)
```

Although you can pass a list with `setParameterList` method after `unwrap` to hibernate's `Query`, which would be the correct way to handle this. See the [javadoc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html) for more details.

Comment: I am not able to find setParameterList in createNativeQuery... Any idea it can be handled in namednativequery?

Comment: I vote for using a prepared statement and binding the collection.  This approach should only be considered with integers, never with strings.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hence my note. I edited it to stress this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. 
I have hibernate and need to delete all as well as delete some records in single method so native query is required here. Delete some records can be 1 100 or 5000. So Using this approach. Need to see if @Namednativequery can also help as i remember in named queries we pass set.

Answer (score 0):

These questions have 2 different answers:

- The best way to join a List into a comma separated String is `StringUtils.join(list, delimiter)` from apache commons (second best would be `String.join(delimiter, list)`)
- The best way to add a list of parameters to a query is `Query.setParameter("id", list)` but I think, you'll have to remove the parentesises from your query for that.

Comment: What i there is no parameter? .... also what should query look like in this approach? <<DELETE FROM PD_OWNER.CIM_SNOW_COMP_OPTDRIV_TAB where id = ? >>

Comment: ...where id IN ?

Comment: and what if no parameter

Comment: I'd strongly advice against SQL concatenating it's a serious security risk. You *should* use parameter binding. I refuse to assist in creating security holes, so no advice for 'no parameter'...

Comment: OK. Security Risk like? just for knowledge